# How to log all SQL queries performed by a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my database that is quite long. I'm wondering if there is a way to print or log all the SQL queries that are performed by this stored procedure?

Comment: Sorry, but what are you going to find? Stored procedure is an SQL-script and you can find all queries it performs directly in it

Comment: I have a stored procedure that is more than 600 lines long, and it has a lot of conditional queries and parameters. So I need to know what queries it performs directly. Otherwise, I'll have to do a very hard and exhausting task of finding which conditions are met and which are not.

Comment: Use an XEvents session, or SQL Profiler. You area looking for the `Stmt:Completed` event. What exatly you have that needs 600 lines is a different question

Comment: 600 lines isn't really all that long, unless each line is an entire query. Sounds to me like it might actually be time well spent to go through this procedure and draw out a flowchart. That would make this type of analysis a lot easier in the future. It might also be a good time to consider if this procedure can be simplified.